# Hide button based on checkbox in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I want to hide `action_invoice_button` based on checkbox,
if my checkbox is true button should be shown else it should be hidden.
here is my code.

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_invoice_open']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('doc_ready', '=', 'False')]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

milan vala

Sometimes there is a minor mistake we forgot to check.

Code:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_invoice_open']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('doc_ready', '=', False)]} </attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Is your field 'doc_ready'  added on your view? if not then do it.

Comment: or you can consider using jquery to hide or not base on the condition.

Comment: yes, I have added 'doc_ready' to view. when I am creating new button and gave invisible attribute to that button it works fine. but it does not work for action_invoice_open inherited button.